# Query sequential dates >= 7 - MSSQL2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to write a query against an MS SQL 2012 database that identifies records where there are 7 or more sequential dates present.  I cannot write to the database, below is an example of my output;

[image]

The highlighted entries are an example of what I want to output.  below is the query I've used to get this far;

```
Declare @From DATETIME
SET @From = '2017-09-11 00:00:00.000'

;WITH RAW AS (SELECT
  ps.ReportDate ReportDate, 
  min (ps.StartTime) Start, 
  max (ps.EndTime) Finish, 
  e.LastName

FROM PayrollSegment ps, Employee e 
WHERE ps.EmployeeKey = e.EmployeeKey AND ps.ReportDate > @From
GROUP BY e.LastName, ps.ReportDate )

SELECT * FROM RAW ORDER BY LastName
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I have to run against the CTE to truncate the data that isn't sequential, thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a classic 'islands' problem. Use two CTEs, the first to find the islands (creating groups of data) and the second to select the groups that you are interested in (i.e. those with 7 or more rows).

Somethings like this should do the trick...

```
WITH GroupedData AS 
(
    SELECT ps.ReportDate,
           ps.StartTime,
           ps.EndTime,
           e.EmployeeKey,
           e.LastName,
           row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY e.LastName ORDER BY ps.StartTime)-datediff(DAY,@From, ps.StartTime) AS GroupId
    FROM PayrollSegment AS ps
    INNER JOIN Employee e ON ps.EmployeeKey = e.EmployeeKey
    WHERE ps.ReportDate > @From
)
,  Group7Day AS
(
    SELECT  g.EmployeeKey,
            g.GroupId
    FROM GroupedData g
    GROUP BY g.EmployeeKey,
             g.GroupId
    HAVING count(1) >= 7
)
SELECT gd.ReportDate,
       gd.StartTime,
       gd.EndTime,
       gd.LastName
FROM GroupedData gd
INNER JOIN Group7Day g7 ON g7.EmployeeKey = gd.EmployeeKey AND g7.GroupId = gd.GroupId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the sequential periods for each employee. Here is example setup script:

```
declare @From datetime = '20170911'

declare @PayrollSegment table(ReportDate datetime, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime, EmployeeKey varchar(10))
insert into @PayrollSegment(ReportDate, StartTime, EndTime, EmployeeKey) values
('20170912', '20170912', '20170912', 'Acton'),
('20170913', '20170913', '20170913', 'Acton'),
('20170914', '20170914', '20170914', 'Acton'),
('20170915', '20170915', '20170915', 'Acton'),
('20170918', '20170918', '20170918', 'Acton'),
('20170919', '20170919', '20170919', 'Acton'),
('20170920', '20170920', '20170920', 'Acton'),
('20170921', '20170921', '20170921', 'Acton'),
('20170922', '20170922', '20170922', 'Acton'),
('20170923', '20170923', '20170923', 'Acton'),
('20170924', '20170924', '20170924', 'Acton'),
('20170925', '20170925', '20170925', 'Acton'),
('20170926', '20170926', '20170926', 'Acton'),
('20170912', '20170912', '20170912', 'Ahn'),
('20170913', '20170913', '20170913', 'Ahn'),
('20170914', '20170914', '20170914', 'Ahn'),
('20170915', '20170915', '20170915', 'Ahn')
```

First find all period starts (i.e. there is no record for ReportDate - 1 for this employee):

```
select
    ReportDate as PeriodStart
from @PayrollSegment ps
where ps.ReportDate >= @From and not exists(select 1 from @PayrollSegment ps2 where ps.EmployeeKey = ps2.EmployeeKey and ps2.ReportDate = DATEADD(day, -1, ps.ReportDate))
```

Then to this query add the corresponding period end (i.e. minimum ReportDate after current one, for the same employee, for which there is no record for ReportDate + 1):

```
select
    ReportDate as PeriodStart
    , (select min(ps3.ReportDate) from @PayrollSegment ps3 where ps3.ReportDate > ps.ReportDate and not exists(select 1 from @PayrollSegment ps4 where ps4.EmployeeKey = ps3.EmployeeKey and ps4.ReportDate = DATEADD(day, 1, ps3.ReportDate))) as PeriodEnd
from @PayrollSegment ps
where ps.ReportDate >= @From and not exists(select 1 from @PayrollSegment ps2 where ps.EmployeeKey = ps2.EmployeeKey and ps2.ReportDate = DATEADD(day, -1, ps.ReportDate))
```

This gives you a list of consecutive days. Just select those periods, which are at least 7 days long:

```
; with cte as (
select
    ReportDate as PeriodStart
    , (select min(ps3.ReportDate) from @PayrollSegment ps3 where ps3.ReportDate > ps.ReportDate and not exists(select 1 from @PayrollSegment ps4 where ps4.EmployeeKey = ps3.EmployeeKey and ps4.ReportDate = DATEADD(day, 1, ps3.ReportDate))) as PeriodEnd
from @PayrollSegment ps
where ps.ReportDate >= @From and not exists(select 1 from @PayrollSegment ps2 where ps.EmployeeKey = ps2.EmployeeKey and ps2.ReportDate = DATEADD(day, -1, ps.ReportDate))
)
select * from cte where DATEDIFF(day, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd) >= 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @PayrollSegment table(ReportDate datetime, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime, EmployeeKey varchar(10))
insert into @PayrollSegment(ReportDate, StartTime, EndTime, EmployeeKey) values
('20170925', '20170925', '20170925', 'Botten'),
('20170926', '20170926', '20170926', 'Botten'),

('20170914', '20170914', '20170914', 'Boyle'),
('20170915', '20170915', '20170915', 'Boyle'),
('20170916', '20170915', '20170915', 'Boyle'),
('20170918', '20170918', '20170918', 'Boyle'),
('20170919', '20170919', '20170919', 'Boyle'),
('20170920', '20170920', '20170920', 'Boyle'),
('20170921', '20170921', '20170921', 'Boyle'),
('20170922', '20170922', '20170922', 'Boyle'),
('20170923', '20170923', '20170923', 'Boyle'),
('20170924', '20170924', '20170924', 'Boyle'),
('20170925', '20170925', '20170925', 'Boyle'),
('20170926', '20170926', '20170926', 'Boyle'),
('20170927', '20170926', '20170926', 'Boyle'),

('20170912', '20170912', '20170912', 'Bridge'),
('20170913', '20170913', '20170913', 'Bridge'),
('20170915', '20170915', '20170915', 'Bridge'),
('20170916', '20170915', '20170915', 'Bridge'),
('20170919', '20170919', '20170919', 'Bridge'),
('20170920', '20170920', '20170920', 'Bridge');


with c as 
( 
  select ReportDate, EmployeeKey, dateadd(day, -1 * dense_rank() over(partition by EmployeeKey order by ReportDate), ReportDate) as grp 
  from @PayrollSegment
),
 c1 as
 ( 
select EmployeeKey, min(ReportDate) as start_range, max(ReportDate) as end_range 
from c 
group by EmployeeKey, grp
having datediff(day, min(ReportDate), max(ReportDate) ) >= 7
)

select *
from @PayrollSegment p join c1
       on p.EmployeeKey = c1.EmployeeKey and p.ReportDate between c1.start_range and c1.end_range;
```

[image]